# Why waveInGetNumDevs returns 0 all the time?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, fft

A few weeks ago `waveInGetNumDevs` function was working well but since few days ago it's been returning 0 all the time. My sound card is OK but why does this happen? I'm actually trying to create an audio visualization for DSPACK. I don't know how to connect `WaveIn` and `TFilterGraph`; and I can't even handle the audio input :(

Comment: Probably you did something to your computer a few weeks ago. Maybe you upgraded the hardware, installed some new audio drivers, or upgraded your operating system?

Comment: @Andreas: hmm, I just installed a new version of directX

Comment: There you go.  This has nothing to do with Delphi, the install of DirectX did something.

Comment: but still, it must work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems indeed that it has something to do with your updating DirectX. Have you tried calling "GetLastError" after the call of waveInGetNumDevs? Maybe you will get to know why you get 0 devs returned all the time.

You should also try the audio input itself with some external app. You might find that it doesn't work altogether and you may simply need to adjust some setting on your card.

Another thing is to see if the driver of your card supports the updated DirectX version!

**Good luck!**